# Plotting over a finite field

Tags: plotting, finite-fields

Is there a way to use a finite field for plotting functions in Mathematica? I couldn't find any options in the documentation.

Comment: Could you please be more specific and give a concrete example of what you are looking for ?

Comment: 'f[u_, v_] = v^2 + (u^2 + u) v - (u^5 + u^3 + 1) 
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -5, 5}'

Where I want 'ContourPlot' to use a finite field as domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether this is what you want.

```
p = Prime[10];
field = Range[0, p - 1];
f[u_, v_] := Mod[v^2 + (u^2 + u) v - (u^5 + u^3 + 1), p];
solutionQ = Subtract[1, Unitize[Outer[f, field, filed]]];
```

`solutionQ` contains a `1` in those positions that belong to a solution pair `{u,v}`.

Plotting:

```
MatrixPlot[
 solutionQ,
 FrameTicks -> {
   Transpose[{Range[Length[field]], field}],
   Transpose[{Range[Length[field]], field}]
   },
 DataReversed -> True,
 Mesh -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the thing I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!